# Jquery- recognize the object being acquired?

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have this assignment :

```
$("myObj").val('1')
```

now lets say I want to add to `1` the existsing value   , so :

```
$("myObj").val($("myObj").val()+'1')
```

*p.s. , I dont want any outside variable to remember the value*

Is there any way to get the object  being acquired ? something like :

[image]

Comment: read the examples here http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with most jQuery functions, `val` takes a callback that is more suited for your use case here:

```
$("myObj").val(function(i, val) {
    console.log(this); //the current dom element that's value is being set
    return val+'1';
});
```

Comment: @AnkitGautam this is what the OP wanted

Comment: @AnkitGautam People also think that Pink floyd is better than the Beatles... so....?  :-)

Comment: I read about the `i - index` param. But what its purpose ? ( `val` is the old value which gonna to be changed , but Index of what ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir index of the element in the jQuery set. For example, if you do `$("input").val( function(index, val){return index;});`, you will see this: http://jsfiddle.net/fUzUP/

Comment: @Esailija I have a question please. in what scenarios I would  use `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` ? we normally send JSON TEXT representation....

Comment: @RoyiNamir When you send a response that is pure json ( **not** JSONP), you would use that header

Comment: but content type is the  for data being posted to server and not the data in response !`When sending data to the server, use this content-type` taken from :http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: In that case, when you send pure JSON to the server. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GvHAb/1/

Comment: so its like sending string .... stringify makes it string. i dont see the difference.

Comment: It's sending pure JSON in the request body, look at the request payload in the network tab of google chrome. There is also http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Comment: I wanted you to see my question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719193/invalid-json-usages#comment15548241_11719193 please tell me if this question deserves the downvotes.... please confirm that I did understand the topic while others didnt ( except 2).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("myObj").val(function(i, oldVal) {
   return oldVal + '1';
})
```

Comment: @diEcho completely pointless and misleading, why would you +1 for that?

Comment: @diEcho Yes, it works. However, `oldVal` is a throwaway variable, so the only advantage of using pre-increment over `oldVal + 1` is completely negated.

Answer (score 0):

```
​$(function(){
    $("input").val(function(){
     return parseInt(this.value, 10)+1;   
    }); 
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T7KGR/

Comment: @diEcho you don't need to specify `10` as the 2nd parameter, this is default.

Comment: From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt): "While this parameter is optional, **always specify it** to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior.  Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified."

Comment: If there is 0 at the beginning so it is radix 8. (parseInt('070')=56)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Cheers Anthony, I wasn't aware of that. I've re-edited my post.

Comment: @ErikE Maybe the OP knows it really good , And just asked a simple question ?( Do something New witht he old value , so just append '1' - it was just an example).

Comment: @Royi I have no doubt as to your knowledge of Javascript. My comment was simply allowing room for adding 1 to possibly be the right answer, though it seemed you wanted concatenation. It was not a slam on you.

Comment: @ErikE It was just a comment :). I really can see How you could think that ( who adds '1' as string ????)  but I was saying , it was just an example :) Thanks .:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can parse the string using the function `Number()` itself.

```
$(".myObj").val('1');
$(".myObj").val(Number($(".myObj").val())+1);
```

### Result:

```
2
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/9jYDT/1/)**