# Invalid Json usages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Sometimes I **[see](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/using-jquery-to-consume-an-asp-net-ashx-from-json-in-two-files/)** people send json  to server as :

```
$.ajax({
url: ...
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
data: { 'page': '100AAAAAf00' },
responseType: "json",
success: ...,
error: ...
});
```

but `{ 'page': '100AAAAAf00' }` is *not* Json.

and were saying contentType is json ...

Json is the text representation.

e.g. : `"{ 'page': '100AAAAAf00' }"`

Am I missing something here ?  ( Does jQuery is doing some translations behind the scenes ?)

Wiki :

> JSON  or JavaScript Object Notation, is a text-based (!!)
>   open standard designed for human-readable data interchange.

Comment: I can only guess, I didn't downvote myself, but: because you start out by saying "it is not json", which is kinda.. well.. not true. SO any question coming from that statement is a bit strange, as it started with a hypothesis that is invalid. You might have gotten away with actually asking "is this JSON" instead of just saying it isn't?

Comment: @Nanne **{ 'page': '100AAAAAf00' } is not Json. TRy to PARSE it and youll see !!!**

Comment: Question is being downvoted because people don't understand, what is your questuon here? `data: { 'page': '100AAAAAf00' },` is absolutely OK. Where did you see that `data` property of `jQuery.ajax();` config object MUST be JSON?

Comment: A lot of people do not understand that Javascript object literals and JSON are not the same thing. I would guess these are the people downvoting.

Comment: There are even forms of JSON that are not syntactically valid javascript. For example `{"hello":"world", "key": "value"}` cannot be evaluated as valid javascript as is. Maybe [this](http://i.imgur.com/ZtmzW.png) helps some people see that they are separate languages. `Javascript.parse` is aliased `eval` to make it more effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax("/", {

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        'page': '100AAAAAf00'
    },
    type: 'POST',
    responseType: "json"

});
```

**Is wrong**. This will send a normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request with the request body:

```
page=100AAAAAf00
```

But since the header is `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`, it is actually **lying** to the server.

To send, real, pure, actual JSON to the server with jQuery, you would use:

```
$.ajax("/", {

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ //If data is string, jQuery will not try to process it
        'page': '100AAAAAf00'
    }),
    type: 'POST',
    responseType: "json"

});
```

Now the request body will be:

```
{"page":"100AAAAAf00"}
```

And that cannot be used with php's `$_POST` at all since it works on the basis of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
so maybe that's why people prefer the former..

One can use Chrome's network tab in developer tools to verify my claims here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sV5m4/1/ - Actual json with json header

[image]

and here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sV5m4/2/ - x-www-form-urlencoded with header that claims to be json

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So my question was in place , right ? I did noticed the problematic situation  code problem.....right ? ( like in my main question sample)...

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes the code sample in your question does not send json but x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: :-(   So I dont understand why this question was downvoted.... I think they didnt know  the difference at all...

Comment: Hi :-) ... If I'm sending JSON string with json content type and set processdata to false , does it STILL do ENCODEURICOMPONENT ? Thanks man.

Comment: @RoyiNamir if you have `data: JSON.stringify(obj)` then it will send JSON.

Comment: Its not what i asked. If i send json string and write : `processdata=false` , will the string STILL be digested  with `EncodeUriComponent` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir ah sorry, a string won't go through encodeURIComponent anyway. Processdata is not even needed to be set to false. I'll fix the answer. If you have google chrome you can always esaily check what is sent.

Comment: but if the string has utf8 chars ? (strange ones...) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir what do you mean? the browser should always send strings as utf8 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple function to convert an object to a JSON string...

```
JSON.stringify({ 'page': '100AAAAAf00' }) // => '{ "page": "100AAAAAf00" }'
```

The other way around...

```
JSON.parse('{ "page": "100AAAAAf00" }') // => { page: '100AAAAAf00' }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example everything is correct and `data` property is an object.

Due to [jQuery.ajax(); docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `data` property could be object, array or string.

If it's an array or an object jQuery serializes it.

Comment: so the data itself is not json.

Comment: If you set a *string*, then you can set the JSON directly. But obviously, anything that is not a string, cannot be JSON (because JSON is a text format).

Comment: In your case it's not JSON. It's an object.